# How can I optimize a long array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a javascript code that pretty much searches on a forum post if there is a certain text (a yugioh card, specifically) and replaces it with a special code. It gets the list of cards to search for from a variable that is an array, defined at the beginning of the script.

Obviously this brings problems, as there are over 7000 yugioh cards, and I have to have an italian version and an english version.

The way the searching works is it has a `for` loop, and it executes a regexp search one card at a time. That means that it loops 7000 times, and Firefox doesn't respond for a few seconds. It also significantly lowers loading times.

```
var card_names = [{
        "en": "Primitive Butterfly",
        "ita": "Primitive Butterfly"
    }, {
        "en": "Essha the Frost Vassal",
        "ita": "Essha the Frost Vassal"
    }];
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('post_body');
for (indexa = 0; indexa < card_names.length; ++indexa) {
    var card_name_ita = card_names[indexa].ita;
    var card_name_en = card_names[indexa].en;
    var card_name_ita_regexp = new RegExp(card_name_ita, "gi");
    var card_name_en_regexp = new RegExp(card_name_en, "gi");
    var replaced_first = 0;
    var replaced_second = 0;
    var replaced_third = 0;
    var replaced_forth = 0;
    for (indexb = 0; indexb < list.length; ++indexb) {
        element = list[indexb];
        if (card_name_en !== card_name_ita) {
            element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/’/g, "'").replace(card_name_en_regexp, function(token) {
                return '<span style="cursor: help; color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="script-info-carta" title="' + encodeURIComponent(card_name_en) + '">' + card_name_en.replace(/ /gi, ' ') + '</span>'
            });
            element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(card_name_ita_regexp, function(token) {
                return '<span style="cursor: help; color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="script-info-carta" title="' + encodeURIComponent(card_name_en) + '">' + card_name_ita.replace(/ /gi, ' ') + '</span>'
            });
        }
        if (card_name_en === card_name_ita) {
            element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/’/g, "'").replace(card_name_en_regexp, function(token) {
                return '<span style="cursor: help; color: red; text-decoration: underline" class="script-info-carta" title="' + encodeURIComponent(card_name_en) + '">' + card_name_en.replace(/ /gi, ' ') + '</span>'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are only two cards in the array, but normally there are 7000+.
I would like to know how I can make this thing run better. I have an external SQL database with all the cards in it, so I thought maybe there is a way of making a chain: Javascript contacts a php page, which in turn gets the db and returns the array of cards. I dont know how I could really do this efficiently, so help is appreciated!

Comment: It's a bad idea to work with large data sets in JS. You can't trust the user's computer or browser. You'd be better of making an AJAX request to the server, search in the database and just return the final results.

Comment: What if you examine the text when a user posts a message and either make the change before it gets saved to the database or mark the possible card with something like a html comment that can be later found and replaced more quickly

Comment: So, you're saying that each time the user loads the page you loop 7000 times through the document to turn every mention to a card into a link to that card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is regex creation in loop each time (that is very expensive), and changing dom tree in each iteration which is expensive operation to.

Answer (score 0):

### Array Chunking

```
    //Copyright 2009 Nicholas C. Zakas. All rights reserved.
    //MIT Licensed
function timedChunk(items, process, context, callback){
    var todo = items.concat();   //create a clone of the original

    setTimeout(function(){

        var start = +new Date();

        do {
             process.call(context, todo.shift());
        } while (todo.length > 0 && (+new Date() - start < 50));

        if (todo.length > 0){
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 25);
        } else {
            callback(items);
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

This is the reference site link(http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/11/timed-array-processing-in-javascript/) where this js method is available.

Also refer this link http://snipplr.com/view/46331/process-large-array/ for timed array processing